# Metodo 'toLocaleString()' me devuelve la hora como 0:00:00

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo una tabla en la BBDD donde almaceno X campos, y su `created_at`. Desde JavaScript recojo este `created_at` y le aplico `.toLocaleString()` para que me muestre la fecha y la hora.

```
new Date(this.table[0].presented).toLocaleString('es-ES');
```

En la BBDD (mysql) se almacena de la siguiente manera: `02/09/21 08:40:39,000000000`

Y en mi plataforma me la muestra así: `9/2/2021 0:00:00` aplicando el `.toLocaleString('es-ES')`

**¿Por que me devuelve 0:00:00, y como hago para que me muestre su hora real?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema parece estar con el formato que devuelves:

```
02/09/21 08:40:39,000000000
```

Al momento de realizar el proceso, se obtiene lo sgte:

```
const date1 = new Date('02/09/21 08:40:39,000000000');
console.log(date1.toLocaleString('es-ES'));
//-> date1 - "Invalid Date"

const date2 = new Date('Noviembre 25, 2021 09:30:25');
console.log(date2.toLocaleString('es-ES'));
//-> date2 - "25/11/2021 9:30:25"
```

Te recomiendo revisar el retorno correcto de la tabla, y corregirlo.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente era un error de la tabla. Se estaba almacenando como timestamp(6) y al formatearlo en el código estaba dando error.